# In Table component, is there a way to use customRender to both set a slot name and a rowSpan

Tags: vue.js, antd

I'm trying to customize a table so that the last column span all the rows and futhermore, not only have the dataIndex printed but instead use a template slot.

The documentation say the following about `customRender`:

> Renderer of the table cell. The return value should be a VNode, or an object for colSpan/rowSpan config
>   `Function(text, record, index) {}|slot-scope`

Using scopedSlot and a customRender let me use the slot as the documentation say

```js
{
   title: "Description",
   dataIndex: "descr",
   scopedSlots: { customRender: "descr" }
}
```

```html
<template slot="descr" slot-scope="value">
  {{value}}
</template>
```

And with this, the rowSpan works fine

```js
{
  title: 'Description',
  dataIndex: 'descr',
  customRender: (value, row, index) => {
  const obj = {
    children: value,
    attrs: {},
  };
  if (index === 0) {
    obj.attrs.rowSpan = 10;
  }
  else {
    obj.attrs.rowSpan = 0;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

So currently I'm trying to combine both of them with no success

```
const renderContent = (value, row, index) => {
  const obj = {
    children: value,
    attrs: {},
  };
  if (index === 0) {
    obj.attrs.rowSpan = 10;
    obj.attrs.align = 'middle';
    obj.attrs.width = 900;
    // obj.attrs.customRender = 'test'
    // obj.customRender = 'test'
    // obj.attrs.scopedSlots = { customRender: 'test' }
    // obj.scopedSlots = { customRender: 'test' }
    // obj.attrs.slots = { customRender: 'test' }
    // obj.slots = { customRender: 'test' }
    // obj.attrs.slots = { customRender: 'test' }
    obj.attrs.fixed = 'left'
  }
  // These two are merged into above cell
  else {
    obj.attrs.rowSpan = 0;
  }
  return obj;
};

 columnasPrestaciones: [
      {
        title: "Percepción",
        dataIndex: "Percepcion"
      },
      {
        title: "Clave",
        dataIndex: "Clave"
      },
      {
        title: "Fiscal",
        dataIndex: "Fiscal"
      },
      {
        title: "Importe",
        dataIndex: "Importe",
        customRender: renderContent
      }
    ],
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm trying to achieve the exact same thing.

Comment: Same here, really want an answer for this.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

[components-table-demo-colspan-and-rowspan](https://www.antdv.com/components/table/#components-table-demo-colspan-and-rowspan)

Inside this example: children(VNode) and colSpan are working at the same time.

```js
const columns = [
  {
    customRender: (text) => {
      return {
        children: <a href="javascript:;">{text}</a>,
        attrs: {
          colSpan: 5,
        },
      };
    },
  },
];
```